# How do you add info to a table from an Entry in sqlite and Tkinter?

Tags: python, sqlite, tkinter

I'm trying to add information to a sqlite3 database from an entry. I also want a dropdown menu to have the data from the database. When I'm doing that, I get a AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'get' error. Could someone help successfully accomplish this?

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os
import sqlite3
window=Tk()
window.title("Scheduling Assistant")
window.geometry("400x300")
addname1=Label(text="Add Last Name:").pack()
addname = Entry(window).pack()
addquality1=Label(text="Add Quality (A,B, Or C):").pack()
addquality = Entry().pack()
def click():
    lstnme=addname.get()
    quality=addquality.get()
    c.execute("INSERT INTO densist VALUES ('lstnme','quality')")
submit=Button(text='Submit',command=click).pack()
conn=sqlite3.connect("dentist0.db")
c=conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS densist(
last_name text,
class text)""")
clicked=StringVar()
c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM densist")
drpdwn=OptionMenu(window,clicked, c.fetchall())
drpdwn.pack()
conn.commit()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code also updates the OptionMenu options when the submit button is clicked

```py
from tkinter import *
import os
import sqlite3

# init window
window=Tk()
window.title("Scheduling Assistant")
window.geometry("400x300")
addname1 = Label(text="Add Last Name:")
addname = Entry()
addquality1 = Label(text="Add Quality (A,B, Or C):")
addquality = Entry()
addname1.pack()
addname.pack()
addquality1.pack()
addquality.pack()

# create table
conn = sqlite3.connect("dentist0.db")
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS densist(
last_name text,
class text)""")

clicked = StringVar()
drpdwn = OptionMenu(window, clicked, [])

def update_menu():
    c.execute("SELECT last_name FROM densist")
    all = c.fetchall()
    print(all)
    drpdwn['menu'].delete(0, 'end')
    for choice in all:
        drpdwn['menu'].add_command(label=choice)


def click():
    lstnme = addname.get()
    quality = addquality.get()
    sql = "INSERT INTO densist VALUES (?,?)"
    c.execute(sql, [lstnme, quality])
    conn.commit()
    update_menu()

submit = Button(text='Submit',command=click)
submit.pack()
drpdwn.pack()

update_menu()

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: @SShield you can accept the answer if is useful to you

Comment: Yes. This helped me a lot. Sorry I didn't accept it right away, I didn't notice the accept feature until now.    :)